# mysql Using a variable in table name

Tags: mysql

I have a stored function and need to prepend the tables with a numeric value

How can I use the @packages_plu etc in the SELECT ?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`fs01`@`%` FUNCTION `pack_isp`(fk_packages_id INT , c TEXT) RETURNS decimal(10,2)
BEGIN
  DECLARE p DECIMAL(10,2);
  SET p = 0;
  SET @packages_plu=CONCAT(c,'_packages_plu');
  SET @products= CONCAT(c,'_products');
  SET @packages= CONCAT(c,'_packages');
SELECT 
    SUM(d.quantity * p.price_each_inc)
INTO p FROM
    1_packages_plu d
        LEFT JOIN
    1_products p ON d.fk_products_id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN
    1_packages g ON g.id = fk_packages_id
WHERE
    d.fk_packages_id = fk_packages_id;
  RETURN p;
END
```

Comment: I have tried the PREPARE & EXECUTE but get an error while updating the function 'Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using prepared statements, it's a little hacky but it works.

See the manual here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html